# How to access values of variables from other class?

Tags: java, oop

Hey guys so I am new to OOP and trying to make my first OOP program. But then I encountered a problem. I don't know why the values hasn't changed even though I put a variable on the parameter of the constructor.

Here is my code:

```
public class Phone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addContacts();
        viewContacts();
        Contacts cont = new Contacts();

    }
    public static void addContacts(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        int number = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        Contacts contacts = new Contacts(name,number);

    }
    public static void viewContacts(){
        Contacts contacts =  new Contacts();
        System.out.println("All contacts");
        System.out.println("Number: " + contacts.getNumber());
        System.out.println("Name: "+ contacts.getName());
    }
}
```

Here is the other class:

```
public class Contacts {
    private String name, message;
    private int number;


    public Contacts(String name, int number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }
    public Contacts(){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

}
```

Comment: Because you're creating a new `Contacts` in each method. It's born in that method and dies when the method ends. You may want a `static` `Contact` variable in `Phone`

Comment: But how can I use the constructor  if I will make a variable in phone

Comment: Just do `contacts = new Contacts(name,number);` in `addContacts` (without declaring a new `Contacts` and remove `Contacts contacts =  new Contacts();` from the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new `Contacts` in each method, which means a `Contacts` is born in that method and dies when the method ends.

A possible solution is to create a `static` `Contacts` variable in `Phone`. It's important that it is declared as `static` because you'll then use it in `static` methods.

To use it in the methods, simply refer to `contact` without declaring a new one.

```
public class Phone {

    static Contacts contacts;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addContacts();
        viewContacts();

    }
    public static void addContacts(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        int number = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        contacts = new Contacts(name,number); // this is the class' Contact

    }
    public static void viewContacts(){
        System.out.println("All contacts");
        System.out.println("Number: " + contacts.getNumber()); // this is the class' Contact
        System.out.println("Name: "+ contacts.getName()); // this is the class' Contact
    }
}
```

An even better solution would be for `addContacts` to return a new `Contacts` and then pass that to `viewContacts`, like this:

```
public class Phone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Contacts contacts = addContacts();
        viewContacts(contacts);
    }

    public static Contacts addContacts(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        int number = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        return new Contacts(name,number);

    }

    public static void viewContacts(Contacts contacts){
        System.out.println("All contacts");
        System.out.println("Number: " + contacts.getNumber());
        System.out.println("Name: "+ contacts.getName());
    }
}
```

Finally (but we're in nitpick territory at this point) `Contacts` seems to represent a single contact, so it should really be called `Contact` and `addContacts` should be called `createContact` or `populateContact`.

Answer (score -1):

Use like below,

```
public class MyClass {
  Contact contact = null;
 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     addContact();
     viewContact();
  }

  private void addContact() {
    //your scanner logic to get input goes here
     ....
    contact = new Contact(name, number);
 }

 private void viewContact() {
    System.out.println("All Contacts");
    System.out.println("Name:" + contact.getName());
    System.out.println("Number:" + contact.getNumber());
 }
```